# Need a regexp to extract a Sub String of the String

Tags: java

I have a string, which is a URL location to a particular file. The string looks like :

```
abc://axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml
```

I want to get the content after *n* occurrences of the character `/`. For instance, from the string above, I want:

```
mn/src/main/resources
```

The content appears after 8 occurrences of `/`, and before last occurrence of `/`. I went through few examples like `X{n}` in regular expressions where *n* occurrences of `X` would be retrieved and given by using `group()`, but in my case the character `/` would be random and need to get the content.

Comment: Don't use *regex* for extracting info from URL, that's why there exists the class [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Comment: @MarounMaroun If sandy wants the text after some fixed number of occurrences, will the URL class help?  It'd be easy enough to get down to the `axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml` part, but if that needs to be split somewhere in the middle, how will URL help?

Comment: The methods in URL doesn't satisfy my requirement stated above ..

Comment: My first instinct is to say that when I see *regex* and URL in the same sentence ;)

Comment: How about using the Apache Commons StringUtils library? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.2.1/index.html . Maybe StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(String str, String separator)

Comment: @John forward slash isn't special, so you don't need to escape it at all…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In that case, `{8}(*./)` Exactly 8 occurrences of something followed by a slash. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern like this captures everything after the eighth slash up to the final slash as group number one:

```
(?:[^/]*/){8}(.*)/[^/]*
```

`(?:[^/]*/)` is a sequence of zero or more non-slashes followed by a single slash. The `(?:…)` is a non-capturing group, since we don't care about that text. `{8}` means to get eight of those (so that we've seen eight slashes). `(.*)` takes the rest of the text into a group, up until `/[^/]*` (the final slash and everything after it). For example:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NSlashes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "abc://axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile( "(?:[^/]*/){8}(.*)/[^/]*").matcher( string );
        if ( m.matches() ) {
            String result = m.group( 1 );
            System.out.println( "result: '"+result+"'" );
        }
    }
}
```

```
result: 'mn/src/main/resources'
```

Comment: i want to replace ij/kl/mn with some text say 'replaced'.. how can i do this with regular expressions in java ?  Assume that the text that needs to be replaces occurs after n occurrences and before m occurrences of '/'

Comment: @sandy While certainly related, that sounds like a different question.  If it's not already answered by some question on the site, it would probably be better to ask it as a genuinely _new_ question, with some examples of the input you have, and the output you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

The regex `".+://(?:[^/]+/){6}(.*)/[^/]*"` will return `mn/src/main/resources` as group(1) for `abc://axs/abc/def/gh/ij/kl/mn/src/main/resources/xx.xml`

It can be interpreted as

- At least one character followed by a colon followed by two slashes
- Many non-slashes followed by a slash (repeated 6 times as a non-capturing group)
- A greedy capturing group
- A slash followed by many non-slashes